# insertar el valor de una variable en un dataset en pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

resulta que tengo el siguiente dataset [image: data_tres]

en el cual debo insertar la columna title(la cual debe contener solo Mr, Mrs,Miss,segun sea el caso) entre las columnas survived and name,

lo hice de la siguiente manera:

```
otra=data_tres['name'].str.split(expand=True) otra[(1)]
```

con esto divido la cadena y extraigo los datos que necesito, esto se guarda en la vbla otra.

```
0          Mr.

1          Mr.
2         Mrs.
3          Mr.
4          Mr.
5          Mr.
6          Mr.
7          Mr.
8        Miss.
9          Mr.
10         Mr.
11         Mr.
```

de esta manera..

¿Cómo hago para insertar esta columna en la posicion que indique mas arriba?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html te es útil?

Comment: @abulafia, ya lo habia probado, no me funciona porq debo pasarle un valor especifico y yo tengo es una variable cargada con la consulta...

Comment: No te entiendo... lo que yo quiero decir es `data_tres.insert(3, "title", otra[1])`

Comment: se inserta la columna en esa posicion, perfecto... pero no me trae los valores de otra, previamente calculados, solo me llena la columna con la palabra otra.....